# Making custom classes xlsxwriter friendly

Tags: python, oop, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm writing some data analysis pipelines in pandas.  One of the columns in the dataframes that I've been working with is made up of objects of custom-written classes that are each initialized with a string, from which I read off various information with regular expressions and store in the object's attributes.  The subclass structure is similar to how one might implement a tree of life (e.g. a Tiger is a sublass of Cat which is a subclass of Animal and frequently -- but not always -- animals with the same superclass will share methods).  It also has some useful methods that I can use for calculations.  For **str** and **repr** methods return the string that was used to initialize it, like so:

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.group = self.__class__.__name__

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name.__repr__()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.__str__()
```

I'm using this bit of code to write the a dictionary of data frames to an excel spreadsheet:

```
        with pd.ExcelWriter(saveas) as writer:
            for key, val in dictionary.items():
                print key
                write_index = not val.data_frame.index.is_integer()
                val.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key, index=write_index)
            writer.save()
```

This means that when I want to view my data frame, I see a string.  I have had no problems using the to_csv() method on data frames that have these objects in them, but when I use the to_excel() method of the pandas data frame, I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 406, in write
    f = float(token)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

So I tracked this down to the code in worksheet.py, and the offending lines look like this:

```
    try:
        f = float(token) ##THIS IS WHERE THE CODE FAILS
        if not self._isnan(f) and not self._isinf(f):
            return self.write_number(row, col, f, *args[1:])
    except ValueError:
        pass

    # Finally try string.
    try:
        str(token)
        return self.write_string(row, col, *args)
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))
```

I've added a comment to the code above to show where the failure happens.  My objects don't have **float** methods, so instead of a ValueError they're throwing TypeErrors.  From the code above, it's clear that if we can pass through to the second try statement that the writing will commence (because my class has a **str** method).  So I gave my custom class a **float** method, which returned a ValueError so that the except clause could be triggered.

However, there were more problems down the line with xlsx writer, a few similar ones pertaining to the lack of certain methods in my class (which I added in each case).  However, this only delays the problems:

```
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\sharedstrings.py", line 95, in _write_si
    string = re.sub('(_x[0-9a-fA-F]{4}_)', r'_x005F\1', string)
```

Now, the issue here (I looked at the code) is that, once the strings have been written to the sheets, xlsxwriter runs some function that gets all of the strings from the written file.  The issue seems to be that once the sheets have been written (everything up to writer.save() passed without error), xlsxwriter assumes that the strings that got written were strings all along, and treats them like it, rather than encasing them in str() functions like they did before.

Now, I could go modify the offending code, but I don't want to have to deal with making that play nicely with updates to xlsxwriter.  I could simply make my class inherit from str, but that seems like unpythonic given that I don't really want to use almost any of the string methods.  Lastly, I could sanitize my dataframe by taking everything in it that's of this subclass and turning it back into a string, but that would mean I have to rewrite a lot of things that I use that depend on being able to use the DataFrame.to_excel method.  Is there anything I can do within the class that saves me from having to inherit everything from str?

Comment: if you're using ipython, try using `%debug` to see what the offending `token` is.

Comment: The offending token is a member of the class that I discussed in the post.

Comment: Are you *sure* that's what token is, seems like float(token) wouldn't raise if that were the case...

Comment: Yes.  I'm sure.  Perhaps I was not clear in the post, but when I add a float method to my class that raises a ValueError, that error is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest way is probably to just implement your own engine to use

```
from pandas import io
class MyXLSWriter(io.excel.xlsx.writer):
     def write_cells(self, cells,*args,**kwargs):
         for cell in cells:
             if isinstance(cell.val,(MyCustomClass1,MyCustomClassN)):
                cell.val = str(cell.val) #or some other representaion...
         io.excel.xlsx.writer.write_cells(self,cells,*args,**kwargs)

my_df.to_excell(fname,engine=MyXLSWriter)
```

I think at least ... I totally did not test it...

Comment: Perhaps I didn't phrase my question clearly.  I already did that.

Comment: Ah, ok.  No problem.  I think I will probably bring this up to the people who work on xlsxwriter and maybe even work on it myself if they'll let me (it would be my first open source contribution!).  It certainly seems like something like this should pass without error.

Comment: @MTrenfield As the xlsxwriter people/person I think you should try to resolve this with the current Pandas or XlsxWriter APIs. It seems to me that a solution along the lines of Joran's should work. I wouldn't be keen to extend XlsxWriter to support writing arbitrary object types.